# How to add Push Notifications on Cordova iOS application?

Tags: plugins, cordova, push-notification

I am following a [tutorial](http://devgirl.org/2012/10/19/tutorial-apple-push-notifications-with-phonegap-part-1/) on how to enable push notifications in a Cordova project on iOS.

If I use the sample project that the author provided, everything is in place and works.

However I need to use the latest Cordova version so I started to make my own project. The Cordova project is created correctly. The problems start when I try to install the push notifications plugin.

On the tutorial the author says to make some changes to the cordova.plist file but why on earth the .plist file doesn't exist in the latest version of Cordova?

Is there another way to enable the plugin? We don't need the .plist?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. Got stuck at the same place. This is what I did
1- Install the Plugin using the CLI - `phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git`
2- Since i could not find the PLIST adding the code to the AppDelegate.m would just create errors. So i found the following link:
[Cordova 2.5.0 - Errors after referencing appDelegate.m to PushPlugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770163/cordova-2-5-0-errors-after-referencing-appdelegate-m-to-pushplugin)
3- Within the above link there is a sample of an appdelegate.m which i copied and replaced in my code. THis way i dont have to play worry about the plist.
4- I copied the rest of the JS and it worked immediately. Hope this helps.

Comment: did it work with developer certificate or you needed a distribution certificate?

Answer (score 0):

you managed it how to solve the problem?
you have to make the changes in the config.xml-file
add: plugin

```
name="PushPlugin" and value="PushPlugin
```

inside config.xml
then add this to you your AppDelegate.m
https://github.com/hollyschinsky/PhoneGapBuildPushProject2/blob/master/PhoneGapBuildPushApp2/Classes/AppDelegate.m

Hope this was helpful - I'm on the same tutorial but couldn't manage the next step - maybe we could help each other a little