# Cordova 2.5.0 - Errors after referencing appDelegate.m to PushPlugin

Tags: plugins, push-notification, cordova, xcode4.5, appdelegate

I have some troubles to get the PushNotification-Plugin in Xcode worked.
Here‘s what I did until now (no errors until the last point):

- I downloaded the newest Plugin from https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/
- I drag and drop the PushNotification folder to the Plugins folder in XCode and selected
  the “Create groups for any added folders” as the copy option
- copied the PushNotification.js outside Xcode into the www-folder of my project
- added a script tag to refer to the PushNotification.js file in my HTML file
- added plugin name="PushPlugin" and value="PushPlugin" inside config.xml

No errors yet (though I thought it might be useful, that you know, what I‘ve done yet)

Ok now the errors start:
I added this code-block with these methods into my AppDelegate.m

```
#pragma PushNotification delegation

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
PushNotification* pushHandler = [self.viewController getCommandInstance:@"PushNotification"];
[pushHandler didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
{
PushNotification* pushHandler = [self.viewController getCommandInstance:@"PushNotification"];
[pushHandler didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo
{
PushNotification* pushHandler = [self.viewController getCommandInstance:@"PushNotification"];
NSMutableDictionary* mutableUserInfo = [userInfo mutableCopy];

// Get application state for iOS4.x+ devices, otherwise assume active
UIApplicationState appState = UIApplicationStateActive;

    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(applicationState)]) {
    appState = application.applicationState;
    }
    [mutableUserInfo setValue:@"0" forKey:@"applicationLaunchNotification"];

    if (appState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
    [mutableUserInfo setValue:@"1" forKey:@"applicationStateActive"];
    } else {
    [mutableUserInfo setValue:@"0" forKey:@"applicationStateActive"];
    [mutableUserInfo setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble: [[NSDate date] 
    timeIntervalSince1970]] forKey:@"timestamp"];
    [pushHandler.pendingNotifications addObject:mutableUserInfo];
    }
 }
```

So this are the errors i receive:

- Use of undeclared identifier 'pushHandler'; did you mean 'onpushHandler'?
- Unknown type name 'PushNotification'; did you mean 'NSNotification'?
- Property 'pendingNotifications' not found on object of type 'NSNotification *' -

I changed 'pushHandler' to 'onpushHandler' - but I don't know if thats right, because the developer of the plugin didn't name it onpushHandler in the first way.

For the other two things I don't know if it is the right way to handle it by changing it into NSNotification

Maybe someone could help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Pushnotification folder in your xcode, does it have 'Pushnotification.m' file or 'PushPlugin.m' file.
If it is PushPlugin.m file then dont copy this the code in AppDelgate.m file. Copy the AppDelegate from the github

If it is PushNotification.m file then just add the code at the top of your AppDelegate.m file

## import "PushNotification.h"

I recommend you to start from scratch by looking this [link](https://github.com/mgcrea/cordova-push-notification).

Comment: thank you very much Linson. But in the github with the newest PushNotifications-PLugin there's no AppDelegate - what should I copy?

Comment: Please go through this https://github.com/hollyschinsky/PhoneGapBuildPushProject2/blob/master/PhoneGapBuildPushApp2/Classes/AppDelegate.m

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I was thinking about writing Holly a comment on her blog. This seems to be the code I'm looking for.

Comment: I tried to vote you up, but I don't have enough reputation - but again thanks.